# Solve a System of mixed SDE and ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, stochastic-calculus

I have a system of differential equation to solve, but it's a mixed system of ODE and SDE. I'm not sure whether there is any way to solve this kind of system or not. My equations are:

```
s'[t] == -a s[t] i[t]
di[t] == (a s[t] i[t] - µ i[t] + c (1 - s[t] -i[t]) i[t]) dt + σ dB
i[0]=.5
s[0]=.5
```

with the parameters `a,c,σ,µ` greater than 0. Is there any known way to solve this numerically?

Comment: @rhermans Yes, It is, I fixed the post.

Comment: Si is this your system system? `{
 s'[t] == -a s[t] i[t],
 i'[t] == (a s[t] i[t] - \[Micro] i[t] + 
     c (1 - s[t] - i[t]) i[t]) + \[Sigma] B'[t],
 i[0] == .5,
 s[0] == .5
 }`

Comment: Yeah, that's my system!

Comment: What about *dB/dt* i.e `B'[t]`?

Comment: dB is a noise, a random noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `RandomFunction` and `ItoProcess` to solve these stochastic differential equations.

```
a = 1;
μ = 0.1;
c = 1;
σ = 0.1;

sol = RandomFunction[ItoProcess[{
  \[DifferentialD]s[t] == -a s[t] i[t] \[DifferentialD]t,
  \[DifferentialD]i[t] == (a s[t] i[t] - μ i[t] + c (1 - s[t] - i[t]) i[t]) \[DifferentialD]t
  + σ \[DifferentialD]W[t]},
  {s[t], i[t]}, {{s, i}, {0.5, 0.5}}, t, W \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1]],
  {0, 20, 0.01}];

ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Cris K, Is there any way to take the mean curve after 100 interations of this routine?

Comment: @Chris K Could you have a look at my question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276606/numerically-solving-a-system-of-sdes-with-levy-noise, it is similar to this with the extension of Levy noise

Comment: @Math I've looked at it (and upvoted, because I'm also curious about the answer), but unfortunately SDEs are outside my area of expertise. Hope someone helps!