# Numerically solving a system of SDE's with Levy noise?

Tags: differential-equations, modeling, stochastic-calculus, system-modeling

Consider this system from the following paper titled: The long-time behaviour of a stochastic SIR epidemic model with distributed delay and multidimensional L´evy jumps

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08219.pdf

Their system reads:

\begin{align}
dS&=\big[A-\mu_1 S(t)-\beta S(t) D(t)\big]dt+\sigma_1 S(t) dW_1(t)+\int_U \lambda_1(u)S(t-)\tilde{N}(dt,du)\\[1ex]
dI&=\big[\beta S(t) D(t)-(\mu_2+\gamma)I(t)\big]dt+\sigma_2 I(t) dW_2(t)+\int_U \lambda_2(u)I(t-)\tilde{N}(dt,du)\\[1ex]
dD&=\big[\eta(I(t)-D(t)]dt+\sigma_4 D(t) dW_4(t)+\int_U \lambda_4(u)D(t-)\tilde{N}(dt,du)
\end{align}

where $S(t-), I(t-)$ and $D(t-)$ are left limits of $S(t), I(t)$ and $D(t)$. $W_i$ are standard Brownian motions with $\sigma_i>0$. $N$ is a Poisson counting measure with compensating martingale $\tilde{N}$ and characteristic measure $\nu$ on a measurable subset $U$ of $(0,\infty)$, satisfying $\nu(U)<\infty$. We assume $\nu$ is a Levy measure such that $\tilde{N}=N(dt, du)-\nu(du)dt$ and assume $\lambda_i:Z\times\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ are bounded and continuous.

How would I plot Figures 1-4 using the nominal values provided in the paper? I will add a bounty when applicable as this question is interesting to me.

**Edit:**

---

From Table 1, the value of parameters:

Figure 1 :

```
A = 0.9; \[Mu]1 = 0.3; \[Beta] = 0.07; \[Gamma] = 0.05; \[Mu]2 = 0.5; \
\[Eta] = 0.09; \[Sigma]1 = 0.15; \[Sigma]2 = 0.25; \[Sigma]4 = 0.27; \
\[Lambda]1 = 0.2; \[Lambda]2 = 0.23; \[Lambda]4 = 0.1;
```

Figure 2 :

```
A = 0.3; \[Mu]1 = 0.3; \[Beta] = 1.3; \[Gamma] = 0.05; \[Mu]2 = 0.5; \
\[Eta] = 0.09; \[Sigma]1 = 0.15; \[Sigma]2 = 0.25; \[Sigma]4 = 0.27; \
\[Lambda]1 = 0.2; \[Lambda]2 = 0.23; \[Lambda]4 = 0.1;
```

Figure 3 :

```
A = 0.6; \[Mu]1 = 0.4; \[Beta] = 0.35; \[Gamma] = 0.2; \[Mu]2 = 0.3; \
\[Eta] = 0.7; \[Sigma]1 = 0.2; \[Sigma]2 = 0.15; \[Sigma]4 = 0.13; \
\[Lambda]1 = 0.5; \[Lambda]2 = 0.7; \[Lambda]4 = 0.3;
```

Figure 4 :

```
A = 0.6; \[Mu]1 = 0.4; \[Beta] = 0.8; \[Gamma] = 0.3; \[Mu]2 = 0.3; \
\[Eta] = 0.2; \[Sigma]1 = 0.169; \[Sigma]2 = 0.15; \[Sigma]4 = 0.13; \
\[Lambda]1 = 0.5; \[Lambda]2 = 0.7; \[Lambda]4 = 0.3;
```

---

Deterministic model as in Figure 3:

```
tmax = 600;
\[Beta] = 0.35;
A = 0.6;
\[Mu]1 = 0.4;
\[Mu]2 = 0.3;
\[Eta] = 0.7;
\[Gamma] = 0.2;
SExDd = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == A - \[Beta] *S[t]*Dd[t] - \[Mu]1*S[t],
    Ex'[t] == \[Beta] *S[t]*Dd[t] - (\[Mu]2 + \[Gamma])*Ex[t],
    Dd'[t] == \[Eta] (Ex[t] - Dd[t]),
    S[0] == 0.2,
    Ex[0] == 0.3,
    Dd[0] == 0.4},
   {S, Ex, Dd},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3} = SExDd;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Orange}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red, Orange}, {"S(t)", "I(t)", "D(t)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.35}], ImageSize -> 550]
```

Deterministic model as in Figure 4:

```
tmax = 300;
\[Beta] = 0.8;
A = 0.6;
\[Mu]1 = 0.4;
\[Mu]2 = 0.3;
\[Eta] = 0.2;
\[Gamma] = 0.3;
SExDd = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == A - \[Beta] *S[t]*Dd[t] - \[Mu]1*S[t],
    Ex'[t] == \[Beta] *S[t]*Dd[t] - (\[Mu]2 + \[Gamma])*Ex[t],
    Dd'[t] == \[Eta] (Ex[t] - Dd[t]),
    S[0] == 0.2,
    Ex[0] == 0.3,
    Dd[0] == 0.4},
   {S, Ex, Dd},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3} = SExDd;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Orange}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red, Orange}, {"S(t)", "I(t)", "D(t)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.25}], ImageSize -> 550]
```

My question is; how do we extend the deterministic code to a stochastic one that includes the Levy term?

---

---

EDIT 2:

When we simulate this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dianli-Zhao/publication/332241627_Threshold_dynamics_of_the_stochastic_epidemic_model_with_jump-diffusion_infection_force/links/5ca85d24a6fdcca26d013e72/Threshold-dynamics-of-the-stochastic-epidemic-model-with-jump-diffusion-infection-force.pdf, our plots, although similar, do not show the effects of Levy noise as what paper shows, any idea why?

The code for new paper:

```
µ(*Natural mortality rate of S,I,*)= {0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.4};
\[Beta] (*Transmission rate*)= {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8};
\[Delta](*Transmission rate*)= {0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.8};
\[Gamma] (*Recovered rate*)= {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3};
\[Sigma]1 (*Intensity of W1(t)*)= {0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.169};
\[Lambda]1 (*Intensity of W2(t)*)= {0.2, 0, 0, 0.15};


tmax = 801; pWe1 = 
 RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW1 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe1[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe1]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1];

pL1 = RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[1], {0, tmax}];
ListStepPlot[{pL1}];

dpL1 = pL1["SliceData", Range[tmax]] // First // Differences;

L1[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL1[[Round[t]]]]/tmax;

eq1 = -s'[t] + (mu  - mu s[t] - beta s[t] i[t]) - 
   sigma1 s[t] i[t] dW1[t] + lambda1  L1[t];
eq2 = -i'[t] + (beta s[t] i[t] - (mu + delta + gamma) i[t]) + 
   sigma1 s[t] i[t] dW1[t] + lambda1  L1[t];

ic = {s[0] == 0.5, i[0] == 0.1};
rul[j_] := {beta -> \[Beta][[j]], gamma -> \[Gamma][[j]], 
   mu -> µ[[j]], delta -> \[Delta][[j]], sigma1 -> \[Sigma]1[[j]], 
   lambda1 -> \[Lambda]1[[j]]};

eqn[j_] := {eq1, eq2} /. rul[j];

sol[j_] := NDSolve[{eqn[j] == {0, 0}, ic}, {s, i}, {t, 0, tmax - 1}];

With[{sol = sol[1], sol2 = sol[2], 
  sol3 = sol[3]}, {Plot[
   Evaluate[s[t] /. {sol, sol2, sol3}], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black, Blue}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(Days)", 20, Black], 
     Style["S(t)", 20, Black]}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Black, Blue}, {"With jumps", 
       "without jumps", "Deterministic"}, 
      LegendFunction -> Framed], {.85, .85}]], 
  Plot[Evaluate[i[t] /. {sol, sol2, sol3}], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black, Blue}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(Days)", 20, Black], 
     Style["I(t)", 20, Black]}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Black, Blue}, {"With jumps", 
       "without jumps", "Deterministic"}, 
      LegendFunction -> Framed], {.8, .8}]]}]
```

Comment: Could you add code with parameters to reproduce Figure 1?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I tried coding in R, I can code the deterministic system and the system with Brownian motion but not with Levy noise. I cannot reproduce figure 1-4 unfortunately, hence my question. I did my other plots in my document using Mathematica(they were ODe's) but I don't know how to solve a SDE system.

Comment: You don't understand. Just add line of code with parameters from Table 1, for example `A=0.9; ...`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sorry for the late reply. Ah, no, but I can if you would like to me if you haven't already done so.

Comment: I think that what @AlexTrounev is trying to point to you is that you should include in latex form the numerical values that we have to use in order to solve the differential equations. Don't code them, just write them down so we don't have to read the full paper

Comment: First of all you have to do the typing. Try to add some Mathematica code that does at least something. It will be easier for others to build on the existing code. You mention that you can code deterministic system. Why not in Mathematica? Is your post about Mathematical at all?

Comment: @yarchik I have added in the deterministic cases. My question is; how do we extend the deterministic framework to a stochastic one that includes the Levy term.

Comment: @bmf I have done so. Please check the edit.

Comment: I came across an answer from Chris K to this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174360/solve-a-system-of-mixed-sde-and-ode, this can potentially help with solving the system with *only* white noise but what about the Levy noise term?

Comment: For numerical implementation Levy jumps see https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Numerical%20approximation%20of%20stochastic%20differential%20equations%20driven%20by%20L%C3%A9vy%20motion%20with%20infinitely%20many%20jumps&author=E.%20Jum&publication_year=2015

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you. I will give it a read. Could you also type a solution out, this way if I get stuck, you have the solution ready and I will award the bounty to you. This question has been bothering me for some time..

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have codded the white noise term in R but still cannot code the Levy term, if you can do this for me, it will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Math Concerning Edit 2, please, pay attention, that they used Euler step with `dt=10^-3`, while we run `NDSolve`, and automatically used RK8. They try to show, that stochastic SIR epidemic model with Levy jumps going to some equilibrium state as deterministic model. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I understand they used Euler method while we used RK, but shouldn’t this give similar plots? What I mean is; in figure 1 (a) and (b), we see the peaks(troughs) generally higher(lower) for the Levy model compared to the white noise model. This is same case for all papers I have read where they plot Levy vs white noise. So my question is, how can we replicate the same plots for models given in this question?

Comment: @Math See update for my answer for Figure 2 from the paper. To compute Figure 1 let take `lambda1=0.1/5`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev `lambda1=0.1/5` with `sigma_1=0.2` gives Figure 1 *BUT* why don't we get the Figure 1 using identical values in the paper?

Comment: @Math Actually we don't know what random process they used to compute Figures 1, 2. Not in this paper, but in any paper they never ever describe what numerical functions they used to simulate random process like Levy jumps. I just use my intuition to generate  `L1[t]` for this case.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Maybe you can try other random processes to match the Figures?

Comment: @Math  We can't match random data in principle. If you like to use `lambda1=0.1` for Figure 1, and `lambda1=0.6` for Figure 2, then just normalize  `L1` as follows   `L1[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL1[[Round[t]]]]/Max[dpL1];`

Comment: @AlexTrounev This does not work..?

Comment: @Math Use code from Update 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To simulate Levy jumps we can use numerical model described in the paper [Analysis of a stochastic SEIS epidemic model with the standard Brownian
motion and Lévy jump](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211379722002261?via%3Dihub). In this model we use `WhiteNoiseProcess[]` and `PoissonProcess[]` to simulate diffusion and jumps as follows

```
SeedRandom[1234];
A (*Recruitment rate*)= { 0.9, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6};
µ1 (*Natural mortality rate of S*)= { 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4};
\[Beta] (*Transmission rate*) = {0.07, 1.3, 0.35, 0.8};
\[Gamma] (*Recovered rate*)= { 0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.3};
µ2 (*General mortality of I*)= { 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3};
\[Eta] (*Exponentially fading memory rate*)= {0.09, 0.09, 0.7, 0.2};
\[Sigma]1 (*Intensity of W1(t)*)= { 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.169};
\[Sigma]2 (*Intensity of W2(t)*)= { 0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.15};
\[Sigma]4 (*Intensity of W4(t)*)= { 0.27, 0.27, 0.13, 0.13};
\[Lambda]1 (*Jump intensity of S*)= { 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5};
\[Lambda]2 (*Jump intensity of I*)= { 0.23, 0.23, 0.3, 0.3};
\[Lambda]4 (*Jump intensity of D*)= { 0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.7};

tmax = 301; pWe1 = 
 RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW1 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe1[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe1]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]; pWe2 = 
 RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW2 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe2[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe2]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]; pWe4 = 
 RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW4 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe4[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe4]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1];

pL1 = RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[1.], {0, tmax}]; pL2 = 
 RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[1.1], {0, tmax}]; pL4 = 
 RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[.9], {0, tmax}]; ListStepPlot[{pL1, 
  pL2, pL4}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Using data shown above we define 3 functions

```
dpL1 = pL1["SliceData", Range[tmax]] // First // Differences; dpL2 = 
 pL2["SliceData", Range[tmax]] // First // Differences; dpL4 = 
 pL4["SliceData", Range[tmax]] // First // Differences;

L1[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL1[[Round[t]]]]/tmax; 
L2[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL2[[Round[t]]]]/tmax; 
L4[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL4[[Round[t]]]]/tmax;
```

With these functions the SDE model can be written in a form

```
eq1 = -s'[t] + (a - mu1 s[t] - beta s[t] d[t]) + sigma1 s[t] dW1[t] + 
   lambda1 s[t] L1[t];
eq2 = -i'[t] + (beta s[t] d[t] - (mu2 + gamma) i[t]) + 
   sigma2 i[t] dW2[t] + lambda2 i[t] L2[t];
eq3 = -r'[t] + (gamma i[t] - mu3 r[t]);
eq4 = -d'[t] + eta (i[t] - d[t]) + sigma4 d[t] dW4[t] + 
   lambda4 d[t] L4[t];

ic = {s[0] == 0.6, i[0] == 0.3, d[0] == 0.05}; 
rul[j_] := {a -> A[[j]], beta -> \[Beta][[j]], 
  gamma -> \[Gamma][[j]], eta -> \[Eta][[j]], mu1 -> µ1[[j]], 
  mu2 -> µ2[[j]], sigma1 -> \[Sigma]1[[j]], sigma2 -> \[Sigma]2[[j]], 
  sigma4 -> \[Sigma]4[[j]], lambda1 -> \[Lambda]1[[j]], 
  lambda2 -> \[Lambda]2[[j]], lambda4 -> \[Lambda]4[[j]]};
```

Numerical solution

```
eqn[j_]: = {eq1, eq2, eq4} /. rul[j];

sol[j_]: = NDSolve[{eqn[j] == {0, 0, 0}, ic}, {s, i, d}, {t, 0, tmax - 1}];
```

Visualization

```
With[{sol = sol[1]}, {Plot[Evaluate[s[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "S"}], 
  Plot[Evaluate[i[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "I"}], 
  Plot[Evaluate[d[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "D"}]}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 1. To compute model described in the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332241627_Threshold_dynamics_of_the_stochastic_epidemic_model_with_jump-diffusion_infection_force) we use Euler method and data

```
SeedRandom[123];

µ(*Natural mortality rate of S,I,*)= {0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.4};
\[Beta] (*Transmission rate*)= {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8};
\[Delta](*Transmission rate*)= {0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.8};
\[Gamma] (*Recovered rate*)= {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3};
\[Sigma]1 (*Intensity of W1(t)*)= {0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.169};
\[Lambda]1 (*Intensity of W2(t)*)= {0.1, 0, 0, 0.15};


tmax = 301; pWe1 = 
 RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW1 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe1[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe1]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1];

pL1 = RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[1], {0, tmax}];



dpL1 = pL1["SliceData", Range[tmax]] // First // Differences;

L1[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL1[[Round[t]]]];

eq1 = -s'[t] + (mu - mu s[t] - beta s[t] i[t]) - 
   s[t] i[t] (sigma1 dW1[t] - lambda1 L1[t]);
eq2 = -i'[t] + (beta s[t] i[t] - (mu + delta + gamma) i[t]) + 
   s[t] i[t] (sigma1 dW1[t] - lambda1 L1[t]);

ic = {s[0] == 0.5, i[0] == 0.1};
rul[j_] := {beta -> \[Beta][[j]], gamma -> \[Gamma][[j]], 
   mu -> µ[[j]], delta -> \[Delta][[j]], sigma1 -> \[Sigma]1[[j]], 
   lambda1 -> \[Lambda]1[[j]]};

eqn[j_] := {eq1, eq2} /. rul[j];

sol[j_] := 
  NDSolve[{eqn[j] == {0, 0}, ic}, {s, i}, {t, 0, tmax - 1}, 
   MaxSteps -> 10^6, Method -> "ExplicitEuler", 
   StartingStepSize -> 0.001];

With[{sol = sol[1], sol2 = sol[2], 
  sol3 = sol[3]}, {Plot[
   Evaluate[s[t] /. {sol, sol2, sol3}], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black, Blue}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(Days)", 20, Black], 
     Style["S(t)", 20, Black]}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Black, Blue}, {"With jumps", 
       "without jumps", "Deterministic"}, 
      LegendFunction -> Framed], {.85, .85}]], 
  Plot[Evaluate[i[t] /. {sol, sol2, sol3}], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black, Blue}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(Days)", 20, Black], 
     Style["I(t)", 20, Black]}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Black, Blue}, {"With jumps", 
       "without jumps", "Deterministic"}, 
      LegendFunction -> Framed], {.8, .8}]]}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: This is very good Sir! But one question; what values were taken for the plots attached in your answer?

Comment: And why is the output of this simulation much more "smooth" than the one in the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08219.pdf#page=19&zoom=100,56,369?

Comment: @Math We don't know what pseudorandom generator state has been used in the paper while in my answer it is fixed as `SeedRandom[1234]`. All other parameters are taken from Table 1, Figure 1.

Comment: Is there a reason why there is a set for each parameter in the code? I presume the first value will be taken while the others are there for other figures, correct?

Comment: @Math It is just parameters from Table 1. For plot above we use first column in a form `rul[1]`.

Comment: @Math Thank you very much!

Comment: I have two last questions to fully understand your code! 1) what is this for: `[[2, 1, 1]]` in `RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]];` ? and 2) why was different values used in `RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[1.1]` and `RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[.9]`?

Comment: @Math Actually value $\mu$ in `PoissonProcess` is not given in the paper discussed. I take values 0.9,1,1.1 as an example of usage this model. In `WhiteNoiseProcess` we select random values to define functions `dW1, dW2, dW4`.

Comment: when trying this for a different model, i get some errors. Here is the question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278804/why-is-there-problems-solving-this-sde-system?noredirect=1#comment696334_278804. I will add another bounty on that question when it allows me.

Comment: @Math Thank you. I run the test with your new model.

Comment: Could you have a look at this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279007/extension-of-numerically-solving-a-system-of-sdes-with-levy-noise?noredirect=1#comment696847_279007. It is an extension of the of this question. I added it here as an addendum but maybe you missed it. I will also add a bounty to this new question.