# Putting a framed legend in this plot?

Tags: legending, ticks

How can I make a framed legend in the question answered by Alex here: [Numerically solving a system of SDE's with Levy noise?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276606/numerically-solving-a-system-of-sdes-with-levy-noise)

When I try the "normal" way, it doesn't do anything.

The code:

```
 SeedRandom[1234];
    A (*Recruitment rate*)= { 0.9, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6};
    µ1 (*Natural mortality rate of S*)= { 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4};
    \[Beta] (*Transmission rate*) = {0.07, 1.3, 0.35, 0.8};
    \[Gamma] (*Recovered rate*)= { 0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.3};
    µ2 (*General mortality of I*)= { 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3};
    \[Eta] (*Exponentially fading memory rate*)= {0.09, 0.09, 0.7, 0.2};
    \[Sigma]1 (*Intensity of W1(t)*)= { 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.169};
    \[Sigma]2 (*Intensity of W2(t)*)= { 0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.15};
    \[Sigma]4 (*Intensity of W4(t)*)= { 0.27, 0.27, 0.13, 0.13};
    \[Lambda]1 (*Jump intensity of S*)= { 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5};
    \[Lambda]2 (*Jump intensity of I*)= { 0.23, 0.23, 0.3, 0.3};
    \[Lambda]4 (*Jump intensity of D*)= { 0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.7};
    
    tmax = 301; pWe1 = 
     RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW1 = 
     Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe1[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe1]}], 
      InterpolationOrder -> 1]; pWe2 = 
     RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW2 = 
     Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe2[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe2]}], 
      InterpolationOrder -> 1]; pWe4 = 
     RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW4 = 
     Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe4[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe4]}], 
      InterpolationOrder -> 1];
    
    pL1 = RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[1.], {0, tmax}]; pL2 = 
     RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[1.1], {0, tmax}]; pL4 = 
     RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[.9], {0, tmax}]; ListStepPlot[{pL1, 
      pL2, pL4}] 
    dpL1 = pL1["SliceData", Range[tmax]] // First // Differences; dpL2 = 
     pL2["SliceData", Range[tmax]] // First // Differences; dpL4 = 
     pL4["SliceData", Range[tmax]] // First // Differences;
    
    L1[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL1[[Round[t]]]]/tmax; 
    L2[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL2[[Round[t]]]]/tmax; 
    L4[t_] := If[t < 1, 0, dpL4[[Round[t]]]]/tmax; 
    eq1 = -s'[t] + (a - mu1 s[t] - beta s[t] d[t]) + sigma1 s[t] dW1[t] + 
       lambda1 s[t] L1[t];
    eq2 = -i'[t] + (beta s[t] d[t] - (mu2 + gamma) i[t]) + 
       sigma2 i[t] dW2[t] + lambda2 i[t] L2[t];
    eq3 = -r'[t] + (gamma i[t] - mu3 r[t]);
    eq4 = -d'[t] + eta (i[t] - d[t]) + sigma4 d[t] dW4[t] + 
       lambda4 d[t] L4[t];
    
    ic = {s[0] == 0.6, i[0] == 0.3, d[0] == 0.05}; 
    rul[j_] := {a -> A[[j]], beta -> \[Beta][[j]], 
      gamma -> \[Gamma][[j]], eta -> \[Eta][[j]], mu1 -> µ1[[j]], 
      mu2 -> µ2[[j]], sigma1 -> \[Sigma]1[[j]], sigma2 -> \[Sigma]2[[j]], 
      sigma4 -> \[Sigma]4[[j]], lambda1 -> \[Lambda]1[[j]], 
      lambda2 -> \[Lambda]2[[j]], lambda4 -> \[Lambda]4[[j]]};
    eqn[j_]: = {eq1, eq2, eq4} /. rul[j];
    
    sol[j_]: = NDSolve[{eqn[j] == {0, 0, 0}, ic}, {s, i, d}, {t, 0, tmax - 1}];
    With[{sol = sol[1]}, {Plot[Evaluate[s[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, 
       PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Green, 
       FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "S"},PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[Green, "S(t)", LegendFunction -> Framed]]], 
      Plot[Evaluate[i[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
       Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
       FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "I"},PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[Blue, "I(t)", LegendFunction -> Framed]]], 
      Plot[Evaluate[d[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
       Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
       FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "D"},PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[Red, "I(t)", LegendFunction -> Framed]]]}]
```

Comment: Your code produces four plots. You have neither said nor shown where you are trying to add the legend, nor what he legend should be. This is not a minimal working example illustrating the problem that you are having.

Comment: The 3 plots that are produced from the code, I would like to add in framed legends inside the plot. Something like `PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Red}, {"S(t)", "A(t)", "I(t)"}, 
   LegendFunction -> Framed]` This was taken for a plot with all 3 lines of the same plot.

Comment: Edit your question. Eliminate the plot or plots that are not involved with the required legend. Show what you have tried so that it is clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BobHanlon Edited. I am trying to put the legends -(Green line) S(t), - (blue line) I(t) and -(red line) D(t) in each respective plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the documentation, you must use lists for the colors and labels in `LineLegend`. And a position must be provided to `Placed`

```
With[{sol = sol[1]}, {
  Plot[Evaluate[s[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1},
   PlotRange -> All,
   Frame -> True,
   PlotStyle -> Green,
   FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "S"},
   ImageSize -> Medium,
   PlotLegends -> Placed[
     LineLegend[{Green}, {"S(t)"},
      LegendFunction -> Framed],
     {.8, .2}]], Plot[Evaluate[i[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1},
   PlotRange -> All,
   Frame -> True,
   PlotStyle -> Blue,
   FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "I"},
   ImageSize -> Medium,
   PlotLegends -> Placed[
     LineLegend[{Blue}, {"I(t)"},
      LegendFunction -> Framed],
     {.8, .8}]],
  Plot[Evaluate[d[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1},
   PlotRange -> All,
   Frame -> True,
   PlotStyle -> Red,
   FrameLabel -> {"Time t (Days)", "D"},
   ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> Placed[
     LineLegend[{Red}, {"I(t)"},
      LegendFunction -> Framed],
     {.8, .8}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the list of colors is unnecessary in these cases as they can be inherited.

Comment: If you use `SetOptions[LineLegend, LegendFunction -> Framed];` then the lines with `PlotLegends` can be simplified to the form `PlotLegends -> Placed[{"S(t)"}, {.8, .2}]`