# Not plotting solution to the coupled non linear ODE system using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I`m trying to solve the following system of non-linear coupled first-order ordinary differential equations:
$$ \frac{dh}{dx}=-h^2c^2 $$
$$ \frac{dc}{dx}=-hc $$
with the conditions:
$$h(5)=5, c(5)=0.79e^{-12.5}$$

Using NDSolve I tried to plot the solution for $h$:

```
 In[1]:= Clear[x]
         sol = NDSolve[{h'[x] == -h[x]^2c[x]^2+1, c'[x] == -h[x]c[x],h[5] == 5, c[5] == 0.79Exp[-12.5] }, {h, c}, {x, -10, 10}]
          Plot[Evaluate[{{h[x]} /. sol}], {x, -10, 10},PlotRange -> All]
```

But unfortunately, I didn`t see a graph, only an empty plot appeared, and error messages before the plot:

```
NDSolve::dsvar: -9.99959 cannot be used as a variable.
NDSolve::dsvar: -9.99959 cannot be used as a variable.
NDSolve::dsvar: -9.59143 cannot be used as a variable.
General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::dsvar will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

[image]

How to solve this, so the plot will generate a graph corresponding to the solution of the equations?

Comment: `Range \[Rightarrow] All` should be `PlotRange -> All`. Please don't use math assistent to input the *right arrow*, simply type `->` is the right way to go. Also, the system becomes stiff at `x == -0.266228` as mentioned in the warning. If it should not  be stiff, please double check if the system itself is correct.

Comment: It's `PlotRange`, not `Range`. And, please don't add [tag:bugs] until the community has confirmed it.

Comment: ok thank you, but there is other problem poping it after I edited my post

Comment: @DanielVainshtein `NDSolve` only gives a solution in the range `(h   /. sol[[1]])["Domain"] (*{{-0.266228, 10.}}*)`

Comment: This time your variable (probably `x`) is polluted. Please always pay attention to the color of variable. If it's empty, it'll (in most cases) be blue, otherwise it's black. Execute `Clear[x, c, h, Derivative]` to remove the pollution.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann changing the range as you wrote from {-10,10} to {-0.266228,10} didn`t help neither?
BTW, how did you get the number -0.266228?

Comment: @Daniel Vainshtein I`m quite sure that changing the range might help. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution range provided by `NDSolve` try:

```
{xmin, xmax} = (h   /. sol[[1]])["Domain"][[1]];(*{-0.266228, 10.}*)
Plot[Evaluate[{{h[x]} /. sol}], {x, xmin, xmax} ]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you have a look at my SDE with levy jumps question? I need help! question:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276606/numerically-solving-a-system-of-sdes-with-levy-noise?noredirect=1#comment697578_276606